# imagecreatefromjpeg + Out of memory problem

Tags: php

Hello All i have following ini variable set in phpini file.

max_execution_time 50000

memory_limit 40M

post_max_size 8M

When i try to make thumbnail of image its gives me following error :

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 30670848) (tried to allocate 14976 bytes)

image size is 700 kb.

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not that single call to imagecreatefromjpeg() but memory that you have allocated earlier. After all, the allocation fails with a memory request for only ~14kB.

Maybe you created images before in the same script without releasing their memory with imagedestroy() or you have another memory problem. In the latter case you could use a debugging tool (e.g. [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/)) to find the memory hog.

Comment: i had try to debug memery usage, before thumbnail function memery usage = 4997244. i also use imagedestroy in thumbnail function after imagejpeg statment. but still error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

What is the resolution of your 700kb image? It doesn't really matter how big the original .JPG is. If it's a very "simple" image, it could literally be 10,000 x 10,000 pixels. When it's loaded/uncompressed by PHP, those pixels will require 10k x 10k x 3 = 286 megabytes (10x squared times 3 for each red/green/blue component value).

And of course, you say you've set memory limit to 40M, but you've run out of memory at just 29.25 meg. Could be that there's an override somewhere in the setup, perhaps in a site-specific web server .conf file, or a .htaccess, which is setting a lower limit than 40M.

Comment: image resolution is : 3700 x 5600

Comment: image resolution is : 3700 x 5600.   There is no chance of override value because my code is looks like :                        ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','1000');                  @move_uploaded_file();                                              _thumbnail($photo_name,125);                                _thumbnail($photo_name,175);                                       _thumbnail($photo_name,360);

Comment: Is the `ini_set()` actually working? If you're on a shared host, the ISP can lock those down and you won't be able to override them. Do a `phpinfo()` in your script just before the critical parts to see if you're able to override. The `(allocated 30670848)` is diagnostics - at the point that error occurs, the memory limit is 30meg, and the script died when it tried to get another 14k at that point.

Comment: only post_max_size is not working. memory limit and max_execution_time variable are set as per ini_set value. the small images like 200 kb in size have no problem.

Comment: also the value of Local Variable only changed by ini_set. Master Variable value is remain same as it was before.