# Allowed memory error while uploading image file in server

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [imagecreatefromjpeg + Out of memory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794197/imagecreatefromjpeg-out-of-memory-problem)

In php to upload a image by re sizing it. while uploading the file file I am getting some error.Blow you can find the error message.

> **Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 69206016) (tried to allocate 17280 bytes) in /home/mangalti/public_html/om/include/common.class.php
>   on line 125**

In the line 125 this the code `$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempFile);`

It is some memory error so i tried `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` but it shows the sample error if I upload a image with size more than 1.7MB. Below the 1.7MB no problem to upload the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794197/imagecreatefromjpeg-out-of-memory-problem?

Comment: Well yes, you're running out of memory. Try to reduce memory usage if possible or increase the limit even further.

Answer (score -1):

try to increase the size of all these also:

```
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size
```

Comment: i have tried this also i have put a php.ini file                        `;Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
memory_limit = 50M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M`

Comment: @ShankarSwamy are you using any kind of cms?? also on which plate form you are running the codes??